# iOS 13 Installed Fonts Retrieval

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-foundation

Is there a way to retrieve a list of Installed Fonts in iPadOS 13.1?

Neither

`CTFontManagerCopyAvailablePostScriptNames`

nor

`[UIFont familyNames]`

would get any of the fonts shown in iPad Settings > General > Fonts. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Xcode 11 now allows you to add a Font privilege entitlement although it appears it made no difference in this case. :(

Comment: As of iOS 14 apple font api's are pretty limited - either you use the font picker controller to get the user installed fonts or you get nothing. You also can't install fonts from arbitrary files or url, you have to use app bundle or on demand resource. Hoping this improves in future iOS...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At first I thought you could use `CTFontManagerCopyRegisteredFontDescriptors` with the kCTFontManagerScopePersistent scope but that always return a CFArrayRef with 0 items. I'm guessing if your own don't install it, you can't see it.

So I found out that enumeration of User Custom Fonts in iPadOS 13 is prohibited. Enumeration will only return system font because of privacy concerns. See [Font Management and Text Scaling WWDC Video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/227/) at timestamp 18:05.

The only way to reach those font is to use the provided `UIFontPickerViewController` class for your font selector with limited customisation.

Comment: Sometimes Apple's "concerns about privacy" does result in missing important functionality. How can knowledge about user installed fonts harm somebody's privacy? And why is this a problem in iOS, and not in macOS? Using the UIFontPickerViewController to select user installed fonts is a messy solution, because all system provided fonts are also being shown.

Comment: Enumerating user fonts would give developers additional data points to create a unique fingerprint of the user, so it makes sense from a privacy perspective to restrict that.

Answer (score 6):

I would like to add to your current answer, that to access custom user installed fonts via `UIFontPickerViewController` you **must add** Fonts Privilege entitlement to your project target.

It can be done in *Project > Select your app target > Signing & Capabilities > 
+ Capability* or just add it to your *.entitlements* file.

[image: Entitlement - Fonts Privilege]